# Name variants for Schufeldt?

Tags: surnames, naming

I have an ancestor Charity Schufeldt (1792-1851, married Wait Hurlburt) that I am researching. To aid in my search, I'm looking for name variants for Schufeldt. So far I have Schufeldt, Zufelt, Shufelt that all appear to valid variations. I was interested if anyone had found any other variations of this surname.

Comment: What techniques have you tried? http://resources.rootsweb.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/soundexconverter is one option. You've omitted Schufelt from your list which would seem an obvious option, as are Shufeld Shufeldt and Schufeld. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/how-can-i-identify-all-the-possible-alternatives-for-a-surname?rq=1 may also suggest some avenues.

Answer (score 4):

FamilySearch does a fairly good job of recognizing name variants, which in many cases can be rather difficult.  They have a [name grouping lookup page here](https://familysearch.org/stdfinder/NameStandardLookup.jsp), which for Schufeldt shows these names:

> schoofield, schoohfield, schufeld, schufeldt, schufelt, sheufelt, shewfeld, shewfelt, shoofelt, shufalt, shufeld, shufeldt, shufelt, shufeltt, shufield, shufields, shufilt

They have a separate grouping for Zufelt:

> zoofelt, zufalt, zufeld, zufelder, zufeldt, zufelt, zufield, zufled, zuflet, zufult

Another name-variant database can be queried on [this WeRelate page](http://www.werelate.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aNames).

When you're stuck for finding a name variant, [this FamilySearch page](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Guessing_a_Name_Variation) gives some ideas about how to guess possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The technique that I proposed in https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2033
gives the following:

Soundex Code for Schufeldt = S143

Other surnames sharing this Soundex Code:
SAFFOLD | SCHOFIELD | SCOFIELD | SEABOLT | SEEFELDT | SEYBOLD | SHEFFIELD | SHIFFLETT | SHIFLET | SHIFLETT | SPALDING | SPAULDING | SUBLETT |

Comment: Could you also describe the technique here for brevity? Thanks.

Comment: That would involve duplicating the answer as well as the question. I provided a link to avoid that.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with explaining the same technique in two different answers. It saves time on the part of those who are reading the answer.

Comment: Marking this question as a duplicate of http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2026 would also save time for readers but that does not seem to have been considered.