# What is the origin of the surname 'Dubé'?

Tags: surnames, france

I been tracking down my family history before they settled in North America. I was very fortunate to be able to track down my mother's side. But with my father's side I was not so fortunate.  We know it's French in origin but i always suspected that it could also be Germanic. I don't know how I should track the surname down. If anyone knows, or has any suggestions, on how I should proceed, that would be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried Soundex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I identify all the possible alternatives for a surname](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/how-can-i-identify-all-the-possible-alternatives-for-a-surname)

Comment: Could you add the time-frame you think your immigrant arrived and why you think there might be a Germanic connection?

Comment: I think the focus here is on the origin of the surname, and the enquiry about variants is only in support of that.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl yes basicly

Comment: Having an approx. date for arrival in "North America" may give clues to how much the surname changed here and what European regions were most likely to have been the home of the immigrant. It makes a difference if is the 1600s or the late 1800s! Also, "Germanic" (without any qualifiers) could mean Holland, Alsace, Switzerland, Scandinavia, as well as Germany and Austria. There are presently about 950 Dube living in Germany (per http://christoph.stoepel.net/geogen/en/Default.aspx), with concentrations around Quedlinburg, but that doesn't help if the surname before emigration was something else!

Comment: The name Dube is French, it comes from the area known as Provence, France. The Dubes were Nobles in the area for long time.

Comment: Welcome to GFH SE!  If you happen to be able to provide a link or reference to where you learned this information it would be great if you could edit your Answer to include it.

Comment: Its African, originated in south Africa among the Zulu tribe

Comment: Sources to support that assertion would greatly improve your answer. You might find it helpful to review our [Help Centre](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Site tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This may be true for some instances of the name, but it's unlikely to be true for the original poster, given the origins of the family.  If you have information showing that the Zulu version is related to the French/German one, please edit your answer to include it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variations may include:

> Dubet, Dube, Dubée, Dubais, Dubaie, Dubey, Dubay, Dubbée, Dubbee, Dubbaie, Dubber, Dubbey, Dubbay, etc.

These answers were borrowed from: http://www.houseofnames.com/dube-family-crest and http://www.houseofnames.com/fc.asp?s=dub%E9 You might also try looking up the variations on House of Names to see where that leads you. I have thought of a few other variations including:

> Dubie, Dubbie, Dubbais, Dubbaie, Dubbet, Dubbe, Dubbeh, Dubeh, Doobay, Doobee, Doobie, Doobeh, Doobé, Doobée...

There are MANY possibilities. Your best chance of figuring out this mystery is using a soundex or sounding out possibilities. You could also try looking up the Germanic spelling by finding out which sounds combined which sound like Dubé...

Another possibility is that the last name was given by occupation. Dubé refers to a brewer in French, so you may wish to look up variations of the surname Brewer as well (http://www.houseofnames.com/brewer-history/German). The last name Brewer is of Germanic origin. You must remember that scribes often recorded names as they sounded or as they thought the names should be... They lacked spelling rules in medieval times. They also may not have been able to speak the languages of the immigrants, so surnames may have been recorded by observing the person. If they were brewing something, their last name became Brewer. Illiterate people also would have no idea how to spell or write their names to help the scribe... This is why we often see people signing an "X" rather than their name on documents when tracing the roots of our family.

Another important factor to remember is that the borders of European countries have been redrawn frequently through history. What your ancestors referred to as Germany may no longer be Germany, or those who told you the stories may be referring to modern day Germany rather than the country it was in the past. Maybe they were just referring to a country which spoke a Germanic language... Your best bet would be to try to find a specific place name (like a city) that your ancestors lived nearby. You will then be able to look at old maps and investigate which country the city was in at any given time... That will help you to decide where you will continue your exciting search. Best of luck!

Comment: Dubé is the name of A brewer, it is does not mean brewer in French at all.

Comment: @J.J.D. When you see wrong answers really the only thing you or I can do is leave a comment and downvote them (you will get privilege for the latter when you have 125 rep). For future reference this is not usually a useful reason to flag an answer (since we can't do anything about it), unless of course there is something very problematic that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Dube and i have done significant research on the name as well as on my DNA. Dube surname comes from France. Originating in Provence. The Ubaye Valley. It doesn't stop there however, sending my DNA to be tested, I found that instead of french, I am in fact greek. turns out the greeks founded massalia in about 600bc and have been living in the area of france ever since. The Dube name originates in Provence France. The same area that the greeks inhabited since 600bc. i have detailed evidence on my findings. I get very excited whenever i talk about this.. haha

Comment: Welcome to GFH.SE! It would be great if you could share any links or other public information that you have as part of your "detailed evidence".

Comment: It is possible that the name originates from Provence (the Southern part of France), but if you look at the distribution of the name Dube in France since the end of the XIXth century, you see a big core around the Vendee (Western part) and nothing in the South. (See [geopatronyme](http://www.geopatronyme.com/cgi-bin/carte/nomcarte.cgi?nom=dube&submit=Valider&client=cdip) ). 
As for the etymology, it could come from the term 'Bé' which around central France could mean a hill or a small river.

Comment: I am new to this site so please forgive me. Is this the only way of communicating on here or can we chat privately? I wanted to discuss further with Julia the Greek theory because I have information that possibly supports this and also wanted to ask user1 how they discovered the Dube family was noble centuries ago. Fascinating info by both. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, K.B.  I'm afraid you can't communicate here privately -- although you're allowed to include contact information in your user profile so that others can contact you if they wish.